# Mailing with attachment

Tags: grails, email

I have my application sending mail on click of a link./

Any way that i can customize this app to send mail with an attachment.

Belwo is my controller code and service code

Controller code

```
 def list = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    [challengeInstanceList: Challenge.list(params), challengeInstanceTotal: Challenge.count()]
}
```

Service Code:'

```
def mailTest() {
  println("in service")
  mailService.sendMail { 
   multipart true
   to "d@gton.com"
   from "d@gton.com"
   cc "d@gton.com"
   bcc "d@gton.com"
   subject "Test Mail"
   body 'Test Mail.'
```

}
 }

Any Inputs??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add attachments with:

```
mailService.sendMail { 
 multipart true
 attachBytes "Some-File-Name.xml", "text/xml", contentOrder.getBytes("UTF-8")
```

There is a description of it in the Plugin [documentation](http://www.grails.org/plugin/mail)

Comment: Thanks Timo. This worked. One question here. In this case, we are hardcoding the file name. In a scenario, where I have to send a dynamic attachment, i.e have a table format data that the user can fill and then click a button that triggers an email with the data as an attachment. Is this possible??